# Mocking the same value between different tests

Tags: jestjs

I have a file called `constants` with a series of string values that get imported into the file where `init()` is defined. I want to setup my test so that the string values are different between each run. Right now I can only seem to have them be the same for *all* test runs.

```js
jest.mock('../src/constants', () => ({
  build: 'dist',
  action: {
    pusher: {
      name: 'montezuma',
      email: 'best@cat'
    },
    gitHubToken: 'exists'
  }
}));

describe('git', () => {
  describe('init', () => {
    it('should execute three commands', async () => {
      await init();

      expect(execute).toBeCalledTimes(3);
    });

    it('should fail if the deployment folder begins with /', async () => {
      // I want the values of constants to be different in here.
    });
  });
});
```

How can I set it up so `action` and `build` have different values in each test run? I've tried moving the `jest.mock` call into each `it` statement but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a better pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName, accessType?)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype) to mock the return value for each unit test case.

E.g.

`contants.ts`:

```js
export function get() {
  return {
    build: 'dist',
    action: {
      pusher: {
        name: 'montezuma',
        email: 'best@cat'
      },
      gitHubToken: 'exists'
    }
  };
}
```

`index.ts`:

```js
import { get } from './constants';

export async function init() {
  return get();
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { init } from './';
import * as constants from './constants';

describe('git', () => {
  describe('init', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
      jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });
    it('t-1', async () => {
      const mConstants = {
        build: '/',
        action: {
          pusher: {
            name: 'asd',
            email: 'as@cat'
          },
          gitHubToken: 'ccsa'
        }
      };
      const spy = jest.spyOn(constants, 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(mConstants);
      const actualValue = await init();
      expect(actualValue).toEqual(mConstants);
      expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it('t-2', async () => {
      const mConstants = {
        build: 'build',
        action: {
          pusher: {
            name: 'zzz',
            email: 'www@cat'
          },
          gitHubToken: 'xxx'
        }
      };
      const spy = jest.spyOn(constants, 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(mConstants);
      const actualValue = await init();
      expect(actualValue).toEqual(mConstants);
      expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58758771/index.spec.ts (7.685s)
  git
    init
      ✓ t-1 (5ms)
      ✓ t-2 (2ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.829s
```

**Update**, we can also change the constants object for each unit test case.

Before running the unit test, we should store the original constants. After each test case is finished, we should restore the original constants. I use `lodash.cloneDeep` method to make a deep clone for constants.

`constants.ts`:

```js
export const constants = {
  build: 'dist',
  action: {
    pusher: {
      name: 'montezuma',
      email: 'best@cat'
    },
    gitHubToken: 'exists'
  }
};
```

`index.ts`:

```js
import { constants } from './constants';

export async function init() {
  return constants;
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { init } from './';
import { constants } from './constants';
import _ from 'lodash';

const originalConstants = _.cloneDeep(constants);

describe('git', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    _.assignIn(constants, originalConstants);
  });
  describe('init', () => {
    it('t-1', async () => {
      Object.assign(constants, {
        build: '/',
        action: {
          ...constants.action,
          pusher: { ...constants.action.pusher, name: 'aaa', email: 'aaa@cat' },
          gitHubToken: 'bbb'
        }
      });
      const actualValue = await init();
      expect(actualValue).toEqual({
        build: '/',
        action: {
          pusher: {
            name: 'aaa',
            email: 'aaa@cat'
          },
          gitHubToken: 'bbb'
        }
      });
    });

    it('should restore original contants', () => {
      expect(constants).toEqual({
        build: 'dist',
        action: {
          pusher: {
            name: 'montezuma',
            email: 'best@cat'
          },
          gitHubToken: 'exists'
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/58758771/v2/index.spec.ts (10.734s)
  git
    init
      ✓ t-1 (7ms)
      ✓ should restore original contants (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.509s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58758771

Comment: Does that require the constant exports to be functions? Is there any way around that?

Comment: @JamesIves Can you edit your question, what code do you want to test. So that I can help. What does your `constants` code looks like?

Comment: @JamesIves Update the answer, please check.